# Choosing Pantone colours in Duotone dialog window in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, pantone, duotone

Anybody knows a workround? It is a real pain just searching through it randomly, wishing you will finally click the Pantone you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just click at the color and choose **Color Libraries**.
If you are looking for a special Pantone number, just type the number and the selector jumps to the color.

[image]

Comment: What was not clear to me, that there is no text box to type in and you just simply need to start typing while you are in the Color Libraries, and not just a number - I needed to start typing "Pantone" and then the number straight after it. Thanks though, you helped me figure that out.

Comment: @JagoRatajczak you do not need the word "Pantone".... merely type a number - -- [**SEE HERE**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMabI.gif)